# Short story about an astronaut who joins a "collective mind" by letting some sort of "blob" attach to his brain

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story in a compilation that I read in the 70s/early 80s at the latest in which a couple of astronauts visit a village where everyone carries a "blob" attached that disfigures them but makes them part of a happy collective mind. The woman decides to join first, the man hesitates and I can't remember if he decides to join or not. Been trying to find it for years, my mum took it away because there might have been some veiled sex scenes somewhere.

Sorry about the vague description. No, it is not That episode of Futurama :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given the limited info, there's a good chance this is "A Song For Lya" by George R. R. Martin as explained in this answer: [Sci-fi story about a planet with a strange religion that makes people want to merge with a parasite and die](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217951/sci-fi-story-about-a-planet-with-a-strange-religion-that-makes-people-want-to-me/217953#217953)

> The initiates start out with a little blob of parasite on them and roam the planet ringing bells. The parasite grows and eventually they join a vast mass of it in underground caves.

Also the answer to this old question [Story about living planet linked to skin lesions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157526/story-about-living-planet-linked-to-skin-lesions/157544#157544)

> ...blobs of fungus/jelly that grow and slowly consume the person (who, in the end, gets joined with the group-mind/communal blob creature).

Comment: Oh wow that's it! Thank you! I even remember the names now! Sorry about the repeated question, I did look around but missed that.  Trying to find the book to buy now lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Since the answer isn't yet checked off, and this disturbing theme never really lets go of one's memory, I'll name two only-partial matches.
(Might help if there is any memory-conflating of story plots.)

["The Puppet Masters" by Heinlein](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1358) has blobs attached to people. But they do *not* voluntarily get one attached; they do not get to choose, and there is nothing happy about it.

It took some searching for this one because of the decades it's been since I read it, but it is just as disturbing even if someone joined a hive mind by free will:

["Methuselah's Children" by Heinlein](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1532) is (apparently) the source of my troubling memory of a woman joining hive mind. The narrator going out to find her encounters a rabbit-like "native" and asks where Mary Sperling is.
The native replies, "Mary Sperling is gone . . . the one who
speaks with you is inextricably myself and not of your kind."

Not a match so much as a recalled theme of joining a hive-mind, and no wearing of blobs.

Comment: Thank you! Similar theme,  gave me something else to find and read :)